# Search with - does not give results?

Tags: magento2, search, sku

**Magento 2.4.6**

Searching a SKU like abc123 works ok, but as soon as a "-" is included like abc123-456, it does not find a single product. Why is that? I am using elasticsearch. Can the search be optimized in any way?

Product with SKU abc123-456 exists and is also visible on frontend.

Thanks!

Comment: Check after run re-indexing command.

Comment: I did reindex, no difference ...